# not able to read txt file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write and read txt files. While the writing process already works, my reading process returns cryptic values which I suppose to be NULL. How can i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE* fptr;

void writeConfig(const char* new_api_key) {
    if ((fptr = fopen("extendedPokeConfig.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
    } else {
        fprintf(fptr, "%s", new_api_key);
        fclose(fptr);
    }
}

char* readConfig() {
    char* present_api_key;

    if ((fptr = fopen("extendedPokeConfig.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        if ((fgets(&present_api_key, 50, fptr)) == NULL) {
            fclose(fptr);
            return "error reading config file";
        }
        else {
            fclose(fptr);
            return present_api_key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't allocate memory for `present_api_key`

Comment: You also seem to have disabled compiler warnings.  `present_api_key` has type `char *`, so `&present_api_key` has type `char **`.  But the first argument to `fgets` needs type `char *`, just as your compiler should have told you.  So this couldn't possibly have worked.  You need to pass a `char *` that points to a validly allocated array.  You forgot to do that.

Comment: @Ôrel okay, i thought that fgets automatically allocates memory for present_api_key.

Comment: @TomKarzes you are right, I missed that. How would I "validly allocate" this array?

Comment: I tried to fix it with "char present_api_key[50];" but that still gives me the same NULL output :/

Comment: Since you’re reading a relatively small fixed number of bytes (50), you could just use a stack (auto) buffer. However, since you’re returning a pointer to that buffer, it can’t be declared in readConfig(). Better to pass a pointer to the buffer to readConfig(), but the return value used to indicate an error is odd (a pointer to a string literal?). I’d suggest rethinking what readConfig() returns (maybe an int).

Alternatively, you could malloc() a buffer in readConfig(), but then you’d have another possible error condition (malloc() failure) and have to remember to free the buffer later.

Comment: Declaring char present_api_key[50] in readConfig() means the variable is out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: @PaulLynch readConfig() needs to return the readed value, because my program uses it in other functions. So the malloc() buffer approach would be my way to go?

Comment: I’m not a fan of using malloc() when the stack will do. Since readConfig()’s called needs the input data, declare a buffer there and pass it to readConfig(). Technically, to be safe you might consider also passing the buffer size (since readConfig() wouldn’t know it). Having a fixed read length of 50 means whomever uses your function has to know this.

Comment: Other than having to handle another error condition (malloc() failure) there’s no problem with dynamically allocating the buffer in readConfig(), except allocating in one place and freeing in another invites memory leaks. However, as written your function returns a pointer to a string literal if the fread() fails, which can’t be passed to free(). The caller has to do a strcmp() to check for the error, which is odd (and needs the same string literal in two places).

Answer (score 1):

You have many choices:

1. You can allocate memory for `present_api_key` function using *alloc functions or `sbrk` syscall and `free` after using `readConfig`.

```c
char* readConfig() {
    char *present_api_key = malloc(50);
...
    fgets(present_api_key, 50, fptr);
...
    return present_api_key;
}
```

Then after using this function you should free output.

```c
char* buf = readConfig();
...
free(buf)
```

1. You can define a global variable using the BSS segment

```c
char present_api_key[50];

void readConfig() {
...
    fgets(present_api_key, 50, fptr);
...
}
```

Then `present_api_key` have value.

3. You can define variable outside of function and pass to it after allocating dynamic memory or using stack.

```c
char buf[50];
readConfig(buf);
```

or

```c
char *buf = malloc(50);
readConfig(buf);
free(buf);
```

Example of working code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONFIG_NAME "extendedPokeConfig.txt"
#define MAX_CONF_LEN 50

FILE *fptr = NULL;

int writeConfig(const char *key) {
  fptr = fopen(CONFIG_NAME, "w");
  if (!fptr)
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);

  fputs(key, fptr);

  fclose(fptr);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int readConfig(char *key) {
  fptr = fopen(CONFIG_NAME, "r");
  if (!fptr)
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);

  fgets(key, MAX_CONF_LEN, fptr);

  fclose(fptr);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
  char buf[MAX_CONF_LEN];

  writeConfig("Hello World\n");
  readConfig(buf);

  printf("%s", buf);
  return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This design is not true. But is similar to your code ...

Comment: I tried using the global variable variant, but still got the same NULL value. But I will try the other steps too :)

Comment: A global variable does not use stack memory, it lives in the [BSS segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss). Also, I would not mention `sbrk()`; there is no reason to use it unless perhaps if you are writing your own memory allocator.

Comment: The problem with the malloc()/free() approach in #1 is that the shown implementation returns a pointer to a string literal if fread() fails. Can't pass that to free(). If the fread() fails, instead of returning the literal, strcpy() it into the allocated buffer.

Comment: @CodeEnjoyer Try `perror()` or `err()` functions to display better logs. Where you get `NULL` ? Which block ? Your problem is on `fopen()` or `fgets()` ?